# JavaScript shortening long if-else

Tags: javascript, html

I am building an application similar to minesweeper where a user will click a square on a grid and the app will tell the user how many of the surrounding squares contain an 'X'.  I have my code working when I only check up, down, left, and right.  My code is beginning to get very long since there are quite a few edge cases to account for.  I am going to begin checking diagonals for 'X's and I want to come up with a shorter way to check these cases.

Can anyone help me develop a for loop or other short hand way to write this code.  Here is what I have so far for a 8x8 grid.

Here is my sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/6y6wzo001w

```
showNumber= () => {
    let Xcounter = 0;
    console.log(this.props.keys)
    console.log(this.props.reduxState.reducer.board[this.props.keys]) 
    if(this.props.keys% 8 ===0){
        if(this.props.reduxState.reducer.board[this.props.keys +1] === 'X'){
          Xcounter++
        }
      }
    if(this.props.keys% 8 ===7){
        if(this.props.reduxState.reducer.board[this.props.keys -1] === 'X'){
          Xcounter++
        }
      }
    if(this.props.keys/8 <1){
      if(this.props.reduxState.reducer.board[this.props.keys +8] === 'X'){
        Xcounter++
      }
    }
    if(this.props.keys/8 >=7){
      if(this.props.reduxState.reducer.board[this.props.keys -8] === 'X'){
        Xcounter++
      }
    }
    if(this.props.keys % 8 !== 0 && this.props.keys % 8 !== 7){
      if(this.props.reduxState.reducer.board[this.props.keys +1] === 'X'){
        Xcounter++

      }
      if(this.props.reduxState.reducer.board[this.props.keys -1]=== 'X'){
        Xcounter++
      }

    }
    if(Math.floor(this.props.keys)/8 > 0 && Math.floor(this.props.keys)/ 8 < 7){
      if(this.props.reduxState.reducer.board[this.props.keys +8] === 'X'){
        Xcounter++

      }
      if(this.props.reduxState.reducer.board[this.props.keys -8]=== 'X'){
        Xcounter++
      }
    }
    if(this.props.id === 'X'){
      this.setState({...this.state, clicked: true, counter: 'X'})
      return this.state.counter;
    }
    this.setState({...this.state, clicked: true, counter: Xcounter})
    return this.state.counter;
  }
```

Comment: I wrote an implementation of Minesweeper in Vue.js about a year ago: https://github.com/franktopel/vue-defuse/blob/master/src/components/VueDefuse.vue Maybe it helps you!

Comment: @connexo Thanks I will check it out.

Comment: Maybe use switch instead of ifs - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an array `this.props.reduxState.reducer.board`of length 64 with `'X'`s or non-`'X'`s, one could simply loop through the x and y directions like so:

```
 let Xcounter = 0;
 //save the board for shorter and more readable code
 let board = this.props.reduxState.reducer.board;
 //the current index we've clicked on
 let c = this.props.keys;
 //we're going to check if we're at the edge of the board.
 //I'll explain these later.
 let minX = c%8 == 0 ? 0 : -1;
 let maxX = c%8 == 7 ? 0: 1;
 let minY = (c-minX)/8 == 0 ? 0 : -1;
 let maxY = (c-minY)/8 == 7 ? 0 : 1;
 for( let x = minX; x <= maxX; ++x ){
     for( let minY = -1; y <= maxY; ++y ){
         if( board[c+x+8*y)] == 'X' ){ Xcounter++; }
     }
 }
 //we also checked the square itself, but we didn't want to
 if( board[c] == 'X' ){ Xcounter--; }
```

This assumes the indeces of the board are from right to left, and then top to bottom, not the other way around (i.e. `board[7]` is the top-right corner, not the bottom-left one).

As far as what this actually does; essentially, we look whether or not we're at the edge of a board, and find the relative x- and y-coordinates we have to check. To visualize:

[image: example board]

Here `minX=0`, because going to the left of the current clicked square `c` would throw us off the board. `maxX=1` though, because we can check to the right of the clicked square. Similarly, we check the y-coordinates.

Comment: The problem here is that when a square is on the left edge, (keys = 0,8,16...) we do not want check the board at the previous index because these squares are not actually adjacent.

Comment: Yeah, I figured. I accounted for that now :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your checks are already correct, let's work with what you already have.

Try to rewrite what you actually have with more condensed style to get an overview as a first step and introduce a board side constant as a second:

```
  showNumber = () => {
    const BOARD_SIDE = 8;
    let Xcounter = 0;
    let keys = this.props.keys;
    let board = this.props.reduxState.reducer.board;
    console.log(keys);
    console.log(board[this.props.keys]);

    for (let edge = BOARD_SIDE; edge < BOARD_SIDE * BOARD_SIDE; edge += BOARD_SIDE) {
      if (keys % edge === 0 && board[keys + 1] === "X") Xcounter++;
      if (keys % edge === (edge - 1) && board[keys - 1] === "X") Xcounter++;
      if (keys / edge < 1 && board[keys + edge] === "X") Xcounter++;
      if (keys / edge >= (edge - 1) && board[keys - edge] === "X") Xcounter++;
      if (keys % edge !== 0 && keys % edge !== (edge - 1)) {
        if (board[keys + 1] === "X") Xcounter++;
        if (board[keys - 1] === "X") Xcounter++;
      }
      if (Math.floor(keys) / edge > 0 && Math.floor(keys) / edge < (edge - 1)) {
        if (board[keys + edge] === "X") Xcounter++;
        if (board[keys - edge] === "X") Xcounter++;
      }
    }

    if (this.props.id === "X") {
      this.setState({ ...this.state, clicked: true, counter: "X" });
      return this.state.counter;
    }

    this.setState({ ...this.state, clicked: true, counter: Xcounter });
    return this.state.counter;
  };
```